# CSS word-spacing doesn't work in Wordpress menu links

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, word-spacing

CSS word-spacing has no effect when used on my  tags inside the wordpress menu bar. But in Dev Tools it appears to be applied properly to the element.

```
.main-navigation .main-menu > li > a {
    color: white;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: maiandra_gd_regular, verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    word-spacing: 0.1em;
}
```

This is the target website:
[www.viayoga.ch](http://viayoga.ch)

Thank you dearly for your help!

Comment: I have the last version of firefox and the word-spacing works for me.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work, just use a bigger value. Try `word-spacing: 1em;`

Comment: Thank you so much! It's just that had the wrong idea about what word-spacing meant. I thought "0" meant "no space between words". Now I know I have to put a negative value.

Comment: @BenViatte I think you would also want to center the border below active link. 
Add 
`.main-navigation li a:before {
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
margin-left: 0; }`
P.S. Thanks for upvoting, would appreciate if you also accepted the answer.